# When should <%# ... %> and <%= ... %> be used?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have been doing some work lately with a Pre-compiled .NET3.5 app so i have had to write alot of inline code and i was just wondering about the usage of the # and = and niether when doing inline code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- <%= is the [equivalent of Response.Write()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5.aspx)
- <%# is for [Binding Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) on Data Bound controls.
- [<%$](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)  to access AppSettings, ConnectionStrings and other values contained within an application's configuration and resource files

Comment: For <%$, i'd like to add that Phil Haack has an excellent post about creating your own Expression Builders: http://haacked.com/archive/0001/01/01/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx (Also read the comments)

Answer (score 5):

I posted a similar question here, this might give you some things to look at:

[ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Especially this page:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/pages/syntax.aspx