# ASP.NET angle bracket with '#' or '='. What's the difference?

Tags: asp.net

> **Duplicate:** [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

---

I work with PHP which uses `<? ?>` or `<?php ?>` as server tags, but what is the meaning and usage in ASP.NET's `<%**#** %>` and `<%**=** %>` ?

Comment: I asked a duplicate question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Comment: Also see this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%# %>` indicates a data binding operation and is only valid within DataBinding controls (such as a DataGrid, ListView, etc).

`<%= %>` is a shortcut to `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write`. It'll call the `.ToString()` method on any object/ method call (execpt for strings, it may be smart enough to not ToString a string).