# What's the actual name of <% %> tags?

Tags: asp.net, tags, markup

Possibly a redundant and useless question, but my colleagues and I refer to <% %> as server tags, but is there an actual name for them?

one i've seen used is calling them Alcohol tags.

**Edited based on answers**

We're referring to them in ASP.NET, but I would've thought they'd use the same name across all languages if they did the same job?

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: No reason they'd use the same name across languages. Think of 'fields' vs 'instance variables'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Server-Side Scripting Delimiters", as laid out in this question/answer here:

> [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags/649458#649458)

Answer (score 4):

In JSP they are called scriptlets, don't know if you were talking about Java though.

Comment: "scriptlets", actually, but I assume that was a typo

Comment: Yes typo... ^^ In every day life I use to call them scriplets, so I transferred the error here, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP, they're "Embedded Code Blocks".

I like to try and not use "tags" except when referring to to HTML or XML tags (the ones that have a start and end)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, they were called "Server Tags" in classical ASP

Answer (score 1):

I've heard them referred to as bee stings. In Ruby/ERB, they're known as "Embedded Ruby".

Answer (score 0):

That's what I use for them, but I've also heard people use the term inline tags.