# What do you call <% %> escape characters in Rails/JSP/etc?

Tags: language-agnostic

I read a book a while back (I don't know which one) that referred to these characters as "corn holders" or something clever.  What do you call these characters across different web technologies that escape into code blocks with <% %>?

Comment: For ASP/ASP.NET, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags/649458#649458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recall Jeff Atwood calling them "bee stings" in a past Stackoverflow Podcast, but I'm not sure if that only applies to the .NET versions

HTH
Alex

Comment: That's it!  Geez, I didn't read it.  I thought that was the best term for something since I heard @ called ampersat (like & is ampersand).  So great.

Answer (score 0):

They are called **scriptles tags** on JSP, they will be coding as the following too :

```
<jsp:scriptlet> 
</jsp:scriplet>
```

and an example of use (JSP)  :

```
<body>
<%! int j= 15; %>
<% for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    out.println("Hello World!<br/>"); %>
<%-- Im a comment --%>
<%= "Bye" %>
</body>
```

there are more of those "bee things" in the above snippet :

```
<%! %>  or <jsp:declaration> </jsp:declaration> 
<%-- --%> 
<%=  %> or <jsp:expression> </jsp:expression>
```

Comment: Actually, no, Their **content** is a scriptlet, not the tags themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard them called "nuggets" but I think that is non-universal, unaccepted slang.  I like it though.