# Information on <%# ... %> in .NET

Tags: asp.net

Can someone point me in the right direction of some information on using:

```
<%# ... %>
```

It seems Google does not like `<%#` as a search term. I don't even know what such a construct is called.

Or maybe someone can give me a brief description of how it works?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a data-binding expression. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) for a start.

Answer (score 1):

This is used to reference DataItems in a DataBound control. Here's the MSDN [ASP.NET data binding overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860#1a).

Answer (score 1):

It's data binding syntax

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040630.htm

Answer (score 0):

It can also be used to get around the error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks" as seen here [link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/5758.aspx)