# <%# %> vs <%= %>

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET “special” tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

What is the difference between `<%# ... %>`, `<%= ... %>` and `<%$ ... %>`?

I couldn't find anything information about this. It's impossible to find "<%=" using a search engine.

Do these tags have a name?

Comment: As far as terminology I think they are called inline expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<%= ... %>` is generally equivalent to Response.Write(...) 
it cannot be used in a control attribute that is runat="server"

`<%: ... %>` (as of .NET v4.0) is an html encoded version of `<%= %>` (as @Eric mentions)

`<%# ... %>` is used in data-binding context for Bind, Eval or Output (as @Ray mentions)

`<%$ ... %>` is used in the context of a control attribute with runat="server" (google "expression builder" also have a look at making a general purpose ['Code' expression builder](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx). it is evaluated when the attribute/Parameter is required by the control.

Answer (score 5):

<%# %> will attempt to databind to a data source, using the Bind() function.  This makes it a two-way function (read and write).

<%= %> will make the data read-only.

Comment: Also <%= %> prints whatever is inbetween the blocks, where as <% %> simply executes those statements

Comment: And now we also have <%: %> for html encoded output as well.

Answer (score 4):

<%# %> is evaluated during data binding. It does not necessarily require Eval() or Bind() and Matthew suggested - I use it frequently to display plain text in a repeater control.

<%= %> is evaluated as the page renders. It is equivalent to calling Response.Write().

Comment: +1 I was about to ask on another answer about "when" each is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

<%# %> can *ONLY* be used in data-binding context.

<%= %> expects a string value which it will then include in the output stream.  So either a string variable or a method which returns a string.  Anything else will cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

I found some good information that clarifies the terminology for your future google searches:

http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/aspnet/syntax/aspnetpagesyntax.aspx

**Code Render Blocks:**

```
<% inline code %>
```

A shortcut for HttpResponse.Write:

```
<%=inline expression %>
```

**Data Binding Expressions:**

```
<%# databinding expression %>
```

In a property:

```
<tagprefix:tagname property = "<%# databinding expression %>" runat="server" />
```

**Server-side comments**, such that they do not appear in the client's page source:

```
<%-- commented out code or content --%>
```