# Difference Between <%: and <%=

Tags: asp.net, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET “special” tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

I hope this isn't too much of a newbie question. I seem to always use the correct syntax, but I don't really understand why I'm using the <%: and <%= in ASP.NET, and I was hoping someone could clarify for me. I [found this article which explains <%= and <%#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2007/02/13/the-difference-between-lt-and-lt-in-asp-net.aspx), but wasn't able to find anything in Google on <%:.

Examples of where I have used the various syntax:

```
<div>
  <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type) %>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type)%>
</div>
```

and

```
<div id="header-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "", "Home" )%></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks for any clarification.

**Possible Answer (per ChrisF):** [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) - not directly asking this question, but the accepted answer includes this new tag.

Comment: @ChrisF - Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't find that when I was searching on here. I'll edit my post to point there and people can feel free to close this if they want. (If anybody has anything to add here, that would be great, too.) Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<%: "some string" %>
```

is equal to:

```
<%= Html.Encode("some string") %>
```

Comment: yes, but `<%: someMvcHtmlString %>` will not be the same as `<%= Html.Encode(someMvcHtmlString) %>` but instead will Asp.net MVC recognize the `MvcHtmlString` and avoid double encoding. Actually, `IHtmlString` in general.

Comment: @lasseespeholt, you are correct. Here's another article for the new Html encoding output syntax: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

Answer (score 3):

`<%:` is a new way to automatically HTML encode your data. Article from [Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx) on it. New to .NET 4.0.

Comment: Important to note is that you opt-out of HTML encoding by passing it an `IHtmlString` (i.e. something that says it knows how to create valid HTML). They're saying that `<%: %>` should entirely replace `<%= %>`.