# how to Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Pages?

Tags: asp.net

where we use `<%@ %>` `<%= %>` `<%# %>` etc.
what else asp tags can be added in asp.net web pages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Answer (score 16):

`<%%>` is short hand for:

```
<script runat="server">
</script>
```

Anyting inside the `<%` and `%>` is server side code.

The other variants are also shortcuts:

- `<%@%>` is a page directrive
- `<%=%>` is short for `Response.Write`
- `<%:%>` is short for `Response.Write`, adding html encoding (introduced with .NET 4.0)
- `<%#%>` is a binding expression

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) is a good reference to all these.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ %> - page directives, Register control
<%= %> - for the server code  
<%# %> - for the eval kind of function its also for the server code
```

Comment: then why this not giving any output Text='<%= DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() %>'

Comment: @ppp it to assign value to control form inline coding

Comment: @Rana  means?? how to set lable value to current date time using this tag?