# <% %> in ASP.NET (embedded code blocks)

Tags: asp.net

I understand what these signify in the markup of the aspx pages ... but I don't not know the full power they can be used for or even the name to denote these special directives.

Example:

can i put conditional statements like ifs or switches

I have seen and used them to bind data from a data set for example

Any input is greatly appreciated

Comment: If your doing Asp.net Webforms, I would refrain from using it too much.  It's better presentation and easier to debug to put that code in the code behind instead of the html portion.

Comment: @ Lareau agreed. I was just interested in the flexibility of them.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

These are code Block tags.

And yes you can wrap serverside code in these tags (examples in C#)

```
<% if (x = y) {
  } else {
  }
%>
```

OR

```
<% if (x = y) {%>
   Write this HTML
<%  } else {%>
   Write this html
<%  }%>
```

There is also

This `<%=SomeVar %>` Which will out put SomeVar to HTML

Answer (score 68):

[Here](http://naspinski.net/post/2012/02/22/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc)) ([or here - in case it moves again](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20170201201834/http://naspinski.net/post/2012/02/22/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc))) is a post I found and stashed away some time ago listing all the different inline server-side tags with examples. There are seven:

1. `<%...%>` runs normal code
2. `<%=...%>` is equivalent to Response.Write()
3. `<%#...%>` is used for databinding expressions
4. `<%$...%>` returns the value of an expression, and can be used in parameters (note: expressions are not code - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx))
5. `<%@...%>` is for page directives, usually at the top of the ASPX file
6. `<%--...--%>` is for comments
7. `<%:...%>` is the same as `<%=` except it HTML-encodes the value

Comment: That link appears dead but the [MSDN article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976112) from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3812341/761771) is pretty good.

Comment: what is unfortunate is that the MSDN article lists `<%@ ... %>` twice in the intro, but does not have any info on `<%: ... %>` server tag, which is what I was looking for...

Here is another link to check out: https://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags

Comment: Still useful in 2021! Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

The MSDN documentation calls them [embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx). You can put pretty much any code you would place in code-behind files and the server will execute them before serving your pages to browsers.

[Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7.aspx) is the name given to one particular type of code block, the one most commonly seen at the top of ASP.NET pages to give the compiler information about your ASP.NET pages. They are delimited by `<%@` and `%>`.

The language of the code blocks is the same one as specified in the directive block. A quick example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p><% string hello = "Hello world!"; Response.Write(hello); %></p>
    <ol>
    <% for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) { %>
        <li><% Response.Write("Item #" + i); %></li>
    <% } %>
    </ol>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your responses. That is going to help with further research on different forms of embedded code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

When the server receives a request for an ASPX page, it generates an in-memory class that inherits from `Page` (or whatever base class you specified). The inherited class translates "normal" markup into static `Response.Write()` calls, `<%...%>` into equivalent code, and `<%= someExpression %>` into `Response.Write(someExpression)`. For the former code block, any valid C# (or VB) should be accepted; for the latter, the embedded code must be a single expression (something you could assign to a variable.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, those symbols indicate to the *server* parsing the page that the code within those tags should be interpreted as code and not HTML.

So, to answer your other question, you can use conditionals and most any other programming features supported by the server.

Check out a quick guide to ASP:
http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp