# Need some detail on usage of <% in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner level programmer. I was using C# variable in the aspx page.

I have seen the usage of **<%** in the aspx page alot.

I need the detail of when to use <% in what requirement like

```
<% 'When to use this?' %>
<%= 'When to use this?' %>
<%@ 'When to use this?' %>
<%# 'When to use this?' %>
```

I am searching for a useful link regarding this but did not found any help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3812307/how-to-embedded-code-blocks-in-asp-net-web-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this could be Helpful.......

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/384425/Server-side-Delimiters-in-ASP-NET`

Answer (score 0):

You can search with name "delimiter in asp.net"  probably google will give you lot of results.

**<% %>** is server code that executes during the page's render phase which can execute the statements written inside the block which help in interacting with server side at runtime.

```
<% { Response.Write("Hello !"; }%>
```

and like wise if you have script function in your page and you want to call that function you can ue this

```
<% =Callfunc()%>
```

And by default in all pages and user controls you can see directives. more here

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`<% 'When to use this?' %>` Similar to classic ASP and is used to add server-side code within your ASPX page such as:

```
<% for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) { %>
    <p>I am added to the page 10 times</p>
<% } %>
```

---

`<%= 'When to use this?' %>` Similar to the example above only the = allows you to "inject" or reference an expression or variable and not a chunk of code. Belows example refers to `MyAnchor` which can be declared in the code behind. `<a href='<%= MyAnchor %>'></a>`

---

`<%@ 'When to use this?' %>` This is used for page and control declarations: `<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"`

---

`<%# 'When to use this?' %>` This is used for databinding

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMyGrid" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="E-mail" SortExpression="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Email").ToString()%>' NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Email", "mailto:{0}").ToString() %>'></asp:HyperLink>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```