# When should Page.Header.DataBind be called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to resolve correct paths to javascript scripts in my head section using:

```
<script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript" />
```

In order to resolve the path I need to call databind using `Page.Header.DataBind();`  What event should I place the databind call in?

Thanks.

Reference: http://leedumond.com/blog/the-controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks/

When I put it in Page_Load as the article suggests it works (only for firefox), but I wonder if this is the correct place.

When I follow this article IE 8 renders:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

and firefox 3.6 correctly renders:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Update:

Fixed browser issues by updating a script reference in a referenced user control to use ResolveUrl.  Now browser issues are fixed.  Still wondering where to put Databind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding `ID and runat="server"` to link (stylesheet), finding control in header, calling databind on link instead of entire header.

Answer (score 3):

Change `<%#` to `<%=`, at which point you no longer need to call `Page.Header.DataBind();`, since you are not doing any actual databinding in your expression.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) for the differences in the ASP.NET tags.

From the master page I use in all my projects:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>' ></script>
```

Comment: When I try doing it this way I get: 
The Controls Collection Cannot Be Modified Because the Control Contains Code Blocks error.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?  I confess to being a bit confused, as my master page <head> section is setup exactly like the one in the reference you just posted, but I do not get any errors at all (Visual Studio 2008 - web application project - .NET 3.5).

Comment: VS2010 Ultimate web app project, .NET 3.5

Comment: Some quick searching indicates that the error only occurs when you (or some other control) attempts to dynamically add a control to the header.  It appears I have never done that, so I have never been bitten by this particular bug.

Comment: I use page theming, so I think some magic gets added to the header.  I do not have code that adds anything to the header at runtime.

Comment: Theming is likely the culprit then - I don't use it on my projects.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue for myself by calling `Page.DataBind()` on `Page_Load`.

Update: Just calling it on `Page_Load` in the master page caused some bugs with gridview commands not working. Putting it inside a `!Page.IsPostBack` check fixes it.