# List of what each of <% means (<%#, <%=, etc...)

Tags: c#, asp.net, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET “special” tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

You know how you can embed property value from code-behind in your page by simply using <%= PropertyFromCodeBehind %> in your .aspx?

Well, I only recently discovered that and I can't seem to find any tutorial that would explain this (and related stuff) in more depth (I only know that <%# is used in conjuction with Eval) - probably because I'm using <% for searches.

So, can anybody provide me with more detail explanation of these tags, or give a link to some tutorial that explains all this? I'm interested in anything that can be learned on this subject; somewhere I saw that you can do fancy stuff like <% for ... %>.

Comment: I would love if we could come up with a title that shows up in a Google/StackOverflow search results when you search for -> ASP.NET <% ...

Comment: Won't ever happen as Google doesn't index on punctuation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Here](http://michielvoo.net/blog/expressions-vs-statements-part-2-asp-net-code-block-types/) is a good place to get started.

There are several different syntaxes:

- **`<%$ %>` Expression Syntax**
- **`<%# %>` Data-Binding syntax**
- **`<%  %>` Evaluated Code Blocks**
- **`<%= %>` Statement and Expression**

New to ASP.NET 4 is the [HTML encoding syntax (haacked)](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx). This is the same as `<%= %>` except the result is HTML encoded (for non `IHtmlString` types). The new syntax is intended to replace `<%= %>`.

- **`<%: %>` HTML Encoded output**

Comment: FYI, the new syntax only encodes if the type of the expression result does not implement IHtmlString.  If it does implement that interface, then it does not do any encoding. This is how MVC can output markup with its HtmlHelper methods and not have the value be escaped.

Comment: @Brian Ball - great addition. All html helpers since MVC2 return `HtmlString` instead of `string`. I'll add this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

See [ScottGU's post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) post to get you started.