# How to use the <%$ server code %> in Asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, syntax

I would like to know how to work with the

```
<%$  %>
```

format in aspx pages, as I see that it can be used in all kind of formats to insert server side values to controls.
How does its called? 
And where can I please read about how to use it, and what are the format options in all kind of controls.

Thanks.

Comment: [Google ASP.NET Expressions](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ASP.NET+Expressions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are ASP.NET Expressions.

A very common usage is when using a resource file, like so

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" text="<%$ Resources: Messages, ThankYouLabel %>" />
```

Read more on them here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

Comment: Nice to have helped you. If you consider the case closed, mark it as answered.