# Asp.net server-side code block explanations

Tags: asp.net, server-side

I've seen many different types of server side code blocks in aspx but never a simple key for what each means.  I know some of these but it's really hard to search for symbols in a search engine! Can you help me out?

```
<% %> 
<%-- --%> 
<%@ %>
<%= %>
<%: %>
<%$ %>
<%# %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- `<% %>` - [Server side code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28vs.80%29.aspx)
- `<%-- --%>` - [Server Side Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- `<%@ %>` - [Page Directive](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- `<%= %>` - [Display value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- `<%: %>` - [HTML Encode](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx)
- `<%$ %>` - [Datasource Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx)
- `<%# %>` - [Binding Expression](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx)

You can find a bit more information about some of them at "[ASP.NET Page Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h.aspx)".

Comment: +1, excellent answer. Just linkify *Resource Value* and it will be perfect.

Comment: Quite annoying that my Google/MSDN-fu couldn't get the resource value one though! Can anyone offer a link?

Comment: @mdm, it's because it's not *Resource Value* :-) It's HTML encode and it is available only in ASP.NET 4.0. `<%$ %>` is more like resource value

Comment: that's useful! did I miss any?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Right you are, it is getting late here -_- I've updated with a link to ScottGu's excellent blog post about it.

Comment: @mdm, it's getting late here as well :-) Once again very good compilation of links.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: Thank you :) @Michael: Hoping that is all of them, I've seen them all in the wild apart from that pesky *HTML Encode*, although I'm sure someone will comment if we have missed any.

Comment: Looks like you're missing one: <%#: -- binding expression, HTML encoded

Comment: The ASP.NET Page Syntax link went bad. Update to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fy30at8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx