# ASP.NET Code Changes in View Source

Tags: html, asp.net

why does my asp.net comment:

```
<!--<asp:HyperLink   
            ID="RandomFacts"   
            runat="server"  
            Text="Random Facts"  
            NavigateUrl="./RandomFacts.aspx">  
            </asp:HyperLink><br />-->
```

turn into:

```
<!--<a id="RandomFacts" href="./RandomFacts.aspx">Random Facts</a><br />-->
```

When I run the code and view the source in my web browser?

Comment: That is a client-side comment, its content will still be seen by ASP.NET. See [Asp.net server-side code block explanations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365017/asp-net-server-side-code-block-explanations). If you don't want the control to be rendered to HTML, comment it with server-side comments: `<%-- --%>`.

Comment: Comment it within `<%--` and `--%>`

Answer (score 1):

You have used HTML comment. You need to replace it with a server side comment (`<%-- --%>`) if you don't want to get any execution of the block on the server:

```
<%--<asp:HyperLink   
        ID="RandomFacts"   
        runat="server"  
        Text="Random Facts"  
        NavigateUrl="./RandomFacts.aspx">  
        </asp:HyperLink><br />--%>
```

Comment: OK, but even if it wasn't commented. Why does it get turned into a different piece of code?

Comment: @user2261573 because asp.net parses the code and transforms it into the link thats asp.net's job. a web browser would not understand unparsed asp.net

Answer (score 0):

An asp control such as `<asp:Hyperlink...`  is only understood by IIS and not the browser. IIS converts each control to the HTML equivalent and therefore `<asp:Hyperlink...` changes to `<a...`

It does this even though you have commented it out because your comment is a client side comment which will only be processed by the browser.