# inline page code for sever controls never works

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I tried the following code, I tried to use inline expressions like <%, ,<%= , why I can't use inline expression with server side control?

In my first line of code, I was trying to follow this article, but it does not work as well. Why? http://todotnet.com/post/2009/04/18/Working-around-Cannot-create-an-object-of-type-SystemBoolean-from-its-string-representation.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>' meta:code='<% txtDate.DataBind(); %>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%= DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>'></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<% DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: "Nothing works" is a very poor description of the problem you're having. You haven't said what you're trying to do, or what results your attempts have produced. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use code blocks (`<%%>`, `<%=%>` and `<%:%>`) inside a server side control. Binding expressions (`<%#%>`) are a different matter.

You need to learn about the differences between the [shortcut server side code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) just randomly trying the different ones, as you seem to be doing will teach you nothing.

You can assign the values in the code behind file:

```
TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: @Oded-It is my first atempt in the question to set current date time in text box.  about meta trick, see 
http://todotnet.com/post/2009/04/18/Working-around-Cannot-create-an-object-of-type-SystemBoolean-from-its-string-representation.aspx

Comment: @Costa - It is clear from the article that it describes a workaround for something that doesn't need a workaround. I still don't understand why it is called the "meta trick", as the word "meta" is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @Oded- you are right there is no real problem, but I am trying to understand why I can't use inline expression in server side control, and from everyone answer I recognize that meta attribute is not that famous.

Comment: @Costa - Because you are trying to execute serverside code inside server side code.

Answer (score 1):

When you [bind](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) an expression `<%# %>` you must have to call `Control.DataBind()` or `Page.DataBind()` to evaluate it.

Comment: I thought I already did when I wrote meta:code='<% txtDate.DataBind(); %>', the question is why the inline code never works

Comment: Because they are **server** controls and their properties can be set via code or binding expression. <% and %> are ASP.NET Code blocks not a binding expression. The link you've post is pointless here.