# How to bind QueryStringParameter in the Page component without using Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I want to bind some query string params in my page directly, not using code behind. I know that I can use `Request.QueryString["param"].ToString();` in the C# code behind, but I want to bind it directly.

Something like:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="Add" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval(Request.QueryString["param"], "~/PartnerOffice.aspx?partnerId={0}") %>' Text="Add New Office" />
```

Is this possible?

Thanks, JiKra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just navigating to another page why use `asp:HyperLink`? Just use a regular `<a>` tag and add your `QueryString` parameters to it:

```
<a href="~/PartnerOffice.aspx?partnerId=<%= Request.QueryString["param"] %>">Add New Office</a>
```

**Edit:**

You can't use code blocks in a server side control. From [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725393/inline-page-code-for-sever-controls-never-works):

> You can't use code blocks (`<%%>`, `<%=%>` and `<%:%>`) inside a
>   server side control. Binding expressions (`<%#%>`) are a different
>   matter.
>
> You need to learn about the differences between the [shortcut server
>   side code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725393/inline-page-code-for-sever-controls-never-works) just randomly trying the different ones, as you
>   seem to be doing will teach you nothing.
>
> You can assign the values in the code behind file:
>
> ```
> TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
> ```

Comment: OK, this works, but - I can't use ~/ path in simple html link, and second, I was just wandering why is such a simple thing so difficult.

Comment: True, you can't use ~/ but you can use / to get to the root of your site and navigate from there. I guess I'm not understanding what's so difficult about the way this works. What makes it difficult?

Comment: Difficult is that I cannot use Request.QueryString["param"] in regular asp.net components.

Comment: Ah, true. You can't use code blocks in a server side control. I've updated my answer.