# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode() do not work in asp.net TextBox control?

Tags: asp.net

My code below:

Test.aspx:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="text" value="<%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ab)%>" runat="server"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.cs:

```
 public partial class Test: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       public string ab;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             ab = "<script>alert('111');</script>";
        }
    }
```

After running the test.aspx page,the textbox value is `<%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ab)%>`

But remove the `runat="server"` string show correct!

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725393/inline-page-code-for-sever-controls-never-works. btw, you can use <%: to html encode (still obviously won't work with your example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a `runat="server"` on a control, it becomes a server control instead of a traditional HTML tag, so the attributes are dealt with on the server. Unfortunately, that means the inline script tags don't always do what you want them to do.

You can do a few things. Either leave off the `runat="server"` like you said, which makes it render exactly as you want, or set the value in the code:

```
myTextBox.Value = "whatever";
```

You can also use data binding, but it's kind of ugly:

```
<input id="myTextBox" runat="server" type="text"
    value='<%# HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("someString") %>' />

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    myTextBox.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @JoeEnos-Thanks for your reply!
assume that set the value in the code 
myTextBox.Value="<script>alert('111');</script>";

Have XSS attack?

Comment: If you're the one putting the text in the response, and you know it's safe, then you're fine. XSS is more about what happens when you let the user post something that will then show up in the response for a different user. For example, in a forum, if you allow someone to post text, and that text shows up to the public, then you've got to deal with cleansing that text.