# What is the difference between these two tags in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET “special” tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

What is the difference between `<%: %>` and `<%= %>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the blog post *[HTML Encoding Code Blocks With ASP.NET 4](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/25/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx)*. Basically the colon version (new to 4.0) does the HTML encoding for you.

Answer (score 3):

`<%= ... %>` is the equivalent of Response.Write(). The `<%: ... %>` tag is identical, except that it auto-html-encodes the value within the tag