# get current user Asp. Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there is a way to get the current user in the `aspx` page,the page with the `html` definitions? (i know how to get it in the `aspx.cs` page)

Comment: The whole point of the ASP model is that you *don't* access such information from the markup page, you put that type of think in the code behind.

Comment: you need to do this in the code behind do something like the following in your Page_Load() method var User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
<%= Page.User.Identity.Name %>
```

[**Page.User Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx)

Comment: do a google search also do this in the code behind on your page load capture the user/domain should be returned then do a split on "\\" into an array and the user name should be array[0]

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code block in the aspx where you want it to show up.

```
<%= System.Environment.UserName %>
```

See [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Use code tags

```
<%= YourMethodToGetTheCurrentUser() %>
```

Comment: This is better, because you can later modify it if for whatever reason you are managing authentication/authorization in a different way (not using User.Identity.Name). I would use a property called UserName with a getter and setter.

Answer (score 2):

You can access any `public` or `protected` variable from the code-behind file in it's `.aspx` file by wrapping your code in these characters:

```
<% if(PublicObject.Property > 0) { %>
    <p>You can write normal HTML, or write strings like this: <%= PublicObject.Property %></p>
<% } %>
```

`<% %>` let's you add logic or commands into a page. You can use this to add `for` loops or `if` statements. `<%= %>` is used to write content directly to the page. This is used to print the contents of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another one:

```
<%= HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
```