# How to use <% %> in ASP.NET MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm a new user with ASP.NET MVC2 and using HTML 5 for my first project. When I use <% %> in image tag, example: ***`<link href="<%: HttpContext.Current %>"Content/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />`***, as you can see, HttpContext in HttpContext.Current is not hightlighted. If I use <%: HttpContext.Current %> in a new line (not in any tag), it works. Do you know what is this and what should I do?

How diffent bettwen <%= %>, <%: %>, <% %>? How to get absolute image path in MVC2? Thanks for watching!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Comment: Thanks, Jason Berkan. I saw.

Comment: I found my answer, thanks!