# How to set Value of HiddenField on Page load and access in Javascript in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hidden-field

I have a Page which contains the image control which displays the images from Specific Folder (Slide Show) using Javascript. I have set the value of HiddenField Value on Page Load and want to access these values using Javascript. But, after setting the value of Hidden Field on Page Load the value of Hidden Field in Javascript shows NULL.

In .aspx page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
     <script type="text/javascript">

         var folderNm = document.getElementById('<%#HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID%>');
         var MaxIndex = document.getElementById('<%#HiddenFieldMaxIndex.ClientID%>');
         var mainImage = document.getElementById('mainImage');
         //mainImage.src = "Presentations/7/Slide1.GIF";
         //Initilize start value to 1 'For Slide1.GIF'
         var currentIndex = 1;

         //NOTE: Set this value to the number of slides you have in the presentation.
         //var maxIndex = 7;
         var maxIndex = MaxIndex;
         alert("Folder Name " + folderNm + "\n MaxIndex  " + MaxIndex);
         function swapImage(imageIndex) {
             //Check if we are at the last image already, return if we are.
             if (imageIndex > maxIndex) {
                 currentIndex = maxIndex;
                 return;
             }

             //Check if we are at the first image already, return if we are.
             if (imageIndex < 1) {
                 currentIndex = 1;
                 return;
             }

             currentIndex = imageIndex;
             //Otherwise update mainImage
             //document.getElementById("mainImage").src = 'PPT/GIFs/Slide' + currentIndex + '.GIF';
             document.getElementById("mainImage").src = 'Presentations/' + folderNm + '/' + 'Slide' + currentIndex + '.GIF';
             // document.getElementById("mainImage").src = 'Presentations/7/Slide' + currentIndex + '.GIF';
             return;
         }
    </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <div>
            <div>

               <%-- <img src="PPT/GIFs/Slide1.GIF" id="mainImage" name="mainImage" width="50%" height="50%" alt="">--%>
                <img  id="mainImage" name="mainImage" width="25%" height="25%" alt="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#" onclick="swapImage(0);">
                    <img src="/images/firstss.png" border="0" alt="First"></a>
                <a href="#" onclick="swapImage(currentIndex-1);">
                    <img src="/images/prev.png" border="0" alt="Previous"></a>
                <a href="#" onclick="swapImage(currentIndex+1);">
                    <img src="/images/nexts.png" border="0" alt="Next"></a>
                <a href="#" onclick="swapImage(maxIndex);">
                    <img src="/images/lasts.png" border="0" alt="Last"></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldMaxIndex" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldFolderName" runat="server" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

In .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string foldername = string.Empty;
            if (Request.QueryString["di"] != null)
            {
                foldername = Request.QueryString["di"].ToString();
                HiddenFieldFolderName.Value = foldername;
                HiddenFieldMaxIndex.Value = Request.QueryString["Files"].ToString();
            }

    }
```

Here, the Hidden Field value shows null in alert() box. Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify

```
<%#HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID%>
```

to

```
<%= HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID %>
```

Do the same for `<%#HiddenFieldMaxIndex.ClientID%>` See [ASP.NET inline expressions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Comment: Also make sure you take the value and not the object itself.

var folderNm = document.getElementById('<%#HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID%>').value;

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE, did you try it with `<%=` instead of `<%#`

Comment: Yes my bad for not correcting that. Should be this:
var folderNm = document.getElementById('<%=HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID%>').value;

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source of your page, do you see the hidden inputs?

If I'm correct (haven't used webforms a lot lately) the buildin asp:HiddenField doens't put the field in the generated HTML. Therefor your javascript function can't find the field and is returning null.

You can use the asp:TextBox component and hide it using css (display:none;). That way the textbox is rendered in the HTML but not visible for the end user (except when he's searching trough the source of the page). You javascript will find the control and will be able to read the value of the text box.

Try to use  tools like Firebug for Firefox or the page inspector for Chrome to deal with this kinds of bugs.

Comment: i have tried TextBox too but still it shows 'null' please any other solution?

Comment: Is the webpage somewhere online? Can you give an URL? Then I can take a look

Answer (score 0):

You already add reference to `jquery`, so why don't you use it?

```
var folderNm= $("#<%= HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID %>").val();
var index= $("#<%= HiddenFieldMaxIndex.ClientID %>").val();

alert("Folder Name " + folderNm+ "\n MaxIndex  " + index);
```

do the same for others..

Even using above only will not work, because when you access hidden fields document may not be ready.

```
 var currentIndex = 1;
   var folderNm  = 0;
   var MaxIndex = 0;
   alert($("#<%= HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID %>").val()); // this will return null

   // but when document ready you can get values, 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        folderNm= $("#<%= HiddenFieldFolderName.ClientID %>").val();
        MaxIndex= $("#<%= HiddenFieldMaxIndex.ClientID %>").val();
        alert("Folder Name " + folderNm+ "\n MaxIndex  " + MaxIndex); 
    });
```

If you need to check this without `jquery` put all your code inside `swapImage` function and check, it will work.

REF : [jquery ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)