# CS1973 error when trying to implement a ListBoxFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, html.listboxfor

I'm trying to implement a very simple multiple select in .NET where the drop-down values are dynamically created.

**The Code:**

I created  a View Model:

```
public class FiltersViewModel
{
    public int[] SelectedNatures { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Natures { get; set; }

    public void FillNatures()
    {
        var repository = new LeadRepository();
        IEnumerable<string> natures = repository.GetNatures();

        var items = new List<SelectListItem> {};
        foreach (var nature in natures)
        {

            items.Add(new SelectListItem {Value = (string) nature, Text = (string) nature});
            Natures = items.ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

I created an instance of the model in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Map()
    {
        var model = new FiltersViewModel {SelectedNatures = new int[] {}};

        model.FillNatures();

        ViewData.Model = model; 

        return View();

    }
```

Then I added in the View:

```
 <%: Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SelectedValues, Model.Values) %>
```

**Error:**

Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named "ListBoxFor"

**Question:**

- Is there a simpler way to implement a multiselect? (I just want to
  create it, then I use ajax to take the input)
- What is the problem in my current code?
- How can I choose a class and id for my select?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but I'm not overly familiar with working with Web Forms. What does the `<%:` syntax do? Have you tried with something like `<%` or `<%=` instead?

Comment: @ChrisPratt See [ASP.NET “special” tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Comment: I would say check to see if you have the reference for `System.Web.Mvc.dll`

Answer (score 0):

It seems this question deals with the same error. I'll try to see if the answer works.