# Javascript-error on finding object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

im stuck with Javascript in Asp.net...
I made a TextBox named tbValidFrom and another named tbValidTo.
I also made two ModalPopups.
Then i try to open the ModalPopupExtenders when the TextBoxes get focus:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tbValidTo').focus(function () {
   $find('ModalPopupExtenderNV1').show();
})
$('#tbValidFrom').focus(function () {
    $find('ModalPopupExtenderNV2').show();
})
</script>
```

but it doesnt finds tbValidTo or ModalPopUpExtender ?

> Runtime-Error in Microsoft JScript: Object expected

Here is one of the two ModalPopupExtenders and TextBoxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbValidFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelNV2" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderNV2" runat="server" TargetControlID="HiddenField6"
       PopupControlID="PanelNewVersion" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" BehaviorID="ModalPopupExtenderNV2"
       Enabled="True" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" />
   </ContentTemplate
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The same as above is with the other ModalPopupExtender and TextBox...

Help would be really nice.
Thanks

Edit: Yes i use a masterpage!

[image]

Fails where it is marked yellow.

Answer (score 0):

your jQuery syntax is wrong.

change your script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#tbValidTo').focus(function () {
   $(this).find('#<%=ModalPopupExtenderNV1.ClientID%>').show();
});
$('#tbValidFrom').focus(function () {
    $(this).find('#<%=ModalPopupExtenderNV2.ClientID%>').show();
})
</script>
```

elements that has `runat="server"` will eventually end with a different ID than you entered in the aspx file.

i used the `<%= %>` to get the 'final' id.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But sadly it still gives me the 'Object Expected'-Error ...

Comment: `$('#tbValidTo').focus(function () {
   $(this).find('#<%=ModalPopupExtenderNV1.ClientID%>').show();`

Comment: can you please view source and show me the evaluated line of this? (<%=ModalPopupExtenderNV1.ClientID%> should evaluate to a real id)

Comment: Added an picture in the description! (Ath the yellow marked point it failed)

Comment: please try to replace `$('#tbValidTo').focus(function () {` with: `$('#tbValidTo').bind('focus', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Can modify the ID's of elements, if you use a Masterpage the element id's will be modified to something like the following : `ctl001_ContentPlaceHolder1_tbValidFrom`

To get around this ASP.NET modification of your elements you can use ASP.NET Inline Expressions to get the rendered ID from the object.

See the answer to the following question for more information on [ASP.NET Inline Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags/16533184#16533184)

You can look at changing the Client ID Mode (The way ASP.NET Modifies IDs when the page is rendered) here :

[ASP.NET Client ID Modes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

**EDIT** :

The AjaxControlToolkit's ModalPopupExtender is not rendered on the page as a html element, therefore you cannot find this item using the ClientID of the ModalPopupExtender.

You must use the BehaviourID to call the show function on.

The below code should work correctly :

```
$('#<%= tbValidTo.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
   $find('ModalPopupExtenderNV1').show();
})
$('#<%= tbValidFrom.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
   $find('ModalPopupExtenderNV2').show();
});
```

This will find the textbox object using the ASP.NET Inline expressions to find the client ID and will then find the behaviour ID and execute the Show method.

Example Markup :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#<%= tbValidFrom.ClientID %>').focus(function () {
       $find('ModalPopupExtenderNV2').show();
    });
});
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbValidFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelNV2" runat="server" RenderMode="Inline" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:modalpopupextender id="ModalPopupExtenderNV2" runat="server" targetcontrolid="HiddenField6"
            popupcontrolid="PanelNewVersion" backgroundcssclass="modalBackground" behaviorid="ModalPopupExtenderNV2"
            enabled="True" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField6" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Panel ID="PanelNewVersion" runat="server">
    testing panel
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks! Had an fast overlook about your sides and tried your solution, but it also still gives me the same Error :/ I will read trough the Articles completely now, mb they help me ...

Comment: @DatRid Please see my updated answer. I have tested that this is working for me correctly.

Comment: Does it matter where i place my script ? I didnt thought so, but this wont work for me :(

Comment: @DatRid I have added the markup that works for me to my answer. Did you use the code that I updated?

Comment: @DatRid Also don't forget to include the `$(document).ready` handler when you are assigning control events on page load. Otherwise they are not assigned.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I use this code. What i did now was: I copied your example-markup into my project, deleted the old ones and ... it still doesnt work, same error again ...

Comment: Uhm sorry, i dont understand what you mean with including the $(document).ready in page load" If you mean that i have to put it into the script-block - did this. If you mean i have to add sth in codebehind in the page_load-event i have nothing there, sorry

Comment: In the final part of my answer I have wrapped the `.focus` code within the `$(document).ready(function() { });`. Read [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for why this is necessary for your current problem. I can understand why you might have gotten it confused with the code-behind but this has nothing to do with the code-behind :)

Comment: Ah okay :) But yeah, I allready included the $(document).ready in my <script></script> ...

Comment: Have you tried the markup that I've supplied to see if that works?

Comment: Quote: 'What i did now was: I copied your example-markup into my project, deleted the old ones(old code -> replaced it with your code)' :) And this wont work :'( And THIS is total crazy: I made a completly new asp.net-application, copied all your code from here and inserted into the new application and it gives me the same error ... http://s1.directupload.net/images/131022/gykby8gj.png

Comment: @DatRid Have you tried using the `ToolkitScriptManager` control? Not sure if it would make a huge difference but I would guess it would be the better of the two choices. i.e. `<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>`

Comment: thanks, tried that also, but it still has the same error :( This makes me go crazy ^^

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that markup there is two chances for the issues.

1. With the ModalPopupExtender. 
   Where you have given the panel "PanelNewVersion" . Seems like its missing in the markup.
2. In the Javascript code. If you want to hide that Popup, give the name of the panel. NOt the name of the ModalPopupextender.

Also you have given an update panel there in page, so you can easily handle the modalpopup in any srever side event of your textbox.

Otherwise, if you want to use the Modal popup ijn client side, use jQuery Modalpopup. That will the better option.

Comment: hey, I dont want to hide the Popup ;)  .Show is not .Hide :) And i have PanelNewVersion but thanks :) Will try this JQuery Modalpopup!

Comment: @DatRid : I just meant 'to Hide' or 'to show'. :) Sorry if that mislead you.. yeah try JQuery. handling the Ajax control popup using jQuery is not a good approach