# How to use <% %> in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tags

I'm new to web programming and I've started from asp.net with c#, there I saw something like this **<% %>** inside the asp page, can someone explain or give links about this thing?

Comment: Not official documentation but a good, short overview: http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-(3c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc).aspx However, get familiar with the [codebehind model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/015103yb(v=vs.100).aspx). Then you create more maintainable, compile-time safe code.

Comment: [Embedded Code Blocks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I suggest you start going trough some literature. Like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178125(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I think that any kind of basic tutorial on ASP.NET covers this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET "special" tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a forum post with links to documentation for the different server tags, but as most links were broken, here is a list with working links:

`<% %>` Embedded code block: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178135(vs.80).aspx

`<%= %>` Page output: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6dwsdcf5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

`<%: %>` HTML encoded page output: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

`<%# %>` Data binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bda9bbfx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

`<%$ %>` ASP.NET expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx

`<%@ %>` Directive: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz702w3e%28VS.80%29.aspx

`<%-- --%>` Server side comments: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4acf8afk%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: There's a great Stack Overflow post about this linked in the ASP.NET tag wiki: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Answer (score 1):

Its basically a way to execute .Net commands inside the asp page.

Eg:

Shows the current date

```
<%=DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()%>
```