# Difference between <script></script> and <% %>

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference in writing JavaScript code between the

```
    <script> JavaScript code goes here </script>
```

tags and the

```
    <% JavaScript code goes here %>
```

tags???

Comment: Yea the first one is valid html tag, the other isn't, more than likely some server side language short tag

Comment: yes...the bottom one isn't JavaScript

Comment: Looks like ASP to me, most likely classic ASP.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like what you might see in a .jsp file. If so, please realize, Java is NOT JavaScript. They are two completely different languages.

Comment: For those of you still playing the home game, they're called **Inline Server Tags.**  Microsoft has a more "official" term, but nobody ever uses it, and it is less googlable.  There are several variants; see here:http://weblogs.asp.net/ahmedmoosa/archive/2010/10/06/embedded-code-and-inline-server-tags.aspx for the Microsoft-specific ones.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags

Comment: @rescuecreative yes... I am using NetBeans to create a page and I have seen that I could make it a .html page and add JavaScript code inside <script> </script> or I can also do it placing the code between the <% %> tags and still works, same goes to the .jsp extension.  I wondered if there's  difference between any of the 2 methods

Comment: Netbeans is an IDE; it implies you're using Java server-side, but nothing else.  It would have been nice if your question were more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example adds JavaScript to an HTML document where it will be interpreted by a web browser.

The second example adds program code (in any language, including JScript) to a Classic ASP program where it will be interpreted by a web server before being sent to a web browser.

Some other systems also use the `<%` syntax, including JSP (which is Java, not JavaScript).

Comment: Thank you for making it clear I think I was confusing JSP with JavaScript! :/

Answer (score 1):

The `<% %>` tag is not HTML. It's used for various server side languages, like ASP and ASP.NET.

If you for example are using ASP, and specified JScript to be the server side script language, then the code inside the `<% %>` tag would be server side script, not client side script.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <script> JavaScript code goes here </script>
> ```

runs in the browser since the HTML language specifies what `<script>` means

> ```
> <% Server code goes here %>
> ```

runs on your server if you're using ASP or some other code-in-HTML-style templating engine, but is not part of HTML so has no meaning to a browser.

Comment: Javascript on the server?  Maybe if you're using node.js.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I was interpreting "JavaScript code goes here" as "Code in some language that looks vaguely like JavaScript goes here".

Comment: @RobertHarvey: In ASP you have the options to use VBScript or JScript, and the latter is the Microsoft implementation of Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The `<% %>` tag allows you to use Ruby on Rails variables and expressions. Whereas the `<script>` tag is merely HTML and is governed by the [rules defined for it](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element).

Summary: You'll use it for pure JavaScript, which is the default and most widely used.