# No Visible controls/output with HTML helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

i have the following code + HTML that does not render any of the controls:
I am trying to place controls in the web page using HTML Helpers but this is giving me no output of controls.

```
<div id="PaymentTypes" name="PaymentTypes" style="display: block">
  <table width="730" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%
          if(Model.PayCompanyDTO.IsMultipleOption==false)
          {
            switch (Model.SinglePaymentTypeAttribute)
            {
              case ("Full"): %>            
                <p><asp:Label ID="lblFull" Visible="true" runat="server">Amount to pay:</asp:Label></p>
                <%Html.Label("lblFull", "1000");
                break;

              case("Partial"):%>
                <% break;%>

              <%case("DD"):%>

                <label id="DDLPay" title="Payment Amounts">Choose Amount: </label>
                <% Html.DropDownList("AmountListDDL",Model.AmountList);
                break;

              default:
                break;                                     
             }
           }
           else
           {
             if(Model.PayCompanyDTO.AllPaymentOptions.Contains("Full"))
             {
               Html.Label("LblRdoFull","Full");%>
                 <input type="radio" name="rdoPay" id="RadioFull" value="Full" title="Amount to Pay" onclick="PaymentTypeChanged()" />  Full

             <%  }

             if(Model.PayCompanyDTO.AllPaymentOptions.Contains("DD"))
             {
               Html.Label("LblRdoDD","Choose Amount");%>
               <input type="radio" name="rdoPay" id="RadioDD" value="DD" onclick="PaymentTypeChanged()" /> DD
             <% }
           }%>
         </td>                                       
       </tr>                                    
     </table>
   </div>

   <div id="DivFull" name="DivFull" style="display:none">
     <% Html.Label("Amount", "1000");%> Amount
   </div>

   <div id="DivDD" name="DivDD" style="display:none">
     Choose Amount:
     <%   Html.DropDownList("AmountListDDL", Model.AmountList);%>
   </div>
```

What can be the possible problem?

Comment: Shouln't HtmlHelpers calls be "<%=", like:
<%= Html.Label("Amount", "1000")%>
to write returned HTML string to response?

Comment: You have not included what the values of `IsMultipleOption` is or what the value of `SinglePaymentTypeAttribute` is. If `SinglePaymentTypeAttribute == "Partial"` or if it's anything but "Full" or "DD" then it won't add anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not render a label on the page:

```
<% Html.Label("Amount", "1000"); %>
```

Where any of the following would render it:

```
<%= Html.Label("Amount", "1000") %>
<%: Html.Label("Amount", "1000") %>
<% Writer.Write(Html.Label("Amount", "1000")); %>
```

The difference is that `<% ... %>` is just executing code (without rendering anything into the page) while `<%= ... %>` and `<%: ... %>` are rendering the result of an expression, effectively calling `Writer.Write` for you. There is also a subtle difference between `<%=` and `<%:` you need to be aware of, the later will automatically html encode its contents (Specially critical when you are not using the `Html.` helpers like `Html.Label`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags).

In order to render your controls:

- You need to update code like this (mixing logic and rendering statements into a single `<% ... %>` block):

  ```
  <%

  ...

  if(Model.PayCompanyDTO.AllPaymentOptions.Contains("Full"))
  {
      Html.Label("LblRdoFull","Full");%>
  ```
- You can split those code blocks, so the the logic is inside a `<% ... %>` block and the rendering statements are inside `<%: ... %>`) blocks. Please note that you need to remove the semicolon at the end of the Html.Label expression. For example, the code above would look like this:

  ```
  <%

  ...

  if(Model.PayCompanyDTO.AllPaymentOptions.Contains("Full"))
  {
  %>
      <%: Html.Label("LblRdoFull","Full") %>
  ```

Alternatively:

- keep your view as you have it and replace:

  ```
  <%
  ...
  Html.Label("LblRdoFull","Full"); %>
  ```
- with

  ```
  <%
  ...
  Writer.Write(Html.Label("LblRdoFull","Full")); %>
  ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: u mean wheneveri have a block where i use both code logic + rendering controls i have to place an additional <%  %>
means:          
                                                     

    <code> <% 
               ..... code+ <%HTML%> .... %>
    </code>