# Using Eval() in .ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, eval

I have a grid view that displays all of uploaded files of an employee (data from SQL DB).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" ShowFooter="false" PageSize="5"
CssClass="table" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="WhiteSmoke"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#6C7A95" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#666666" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" HeaderStyle-BorderWidth="2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" EmptyDataText="No Documents">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="file_name" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="upload_date" HeaderText="Date (GMT -7)" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="file_status" HeaderText="Status" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee's Note">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <a data-original-title='<%# Eval("emp_note")%>' href="#" class="demo-cancel-click" rel="tooltip"><i class="icon-book"></i></a>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The interface look like this:
[image]

The Employee's Note (**emp_note**) is an optional field (emp_note can be null in database), how can I make the "icon-book" disappear if the emp_note is empty in database?

I tried this but got error:

```
<a data-original-title='<%# Eval("emp_note")%>' href="#" class="demo-cancel-click" rel="tooltip"><i class="<%= Eval("emp_note") != null ? "icon-book" : ""%>"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have wrong quotes for the `class` value of the `i` tag. Also `<%# %>` should be used there, just as for the `a`:

```
<i class='<%# Eval("emp_note") != null ? "icon-book" : ""%>'></i>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, please recommend me some articles that show the using this kind of functions (Eval() ...etc) in .aspx file, in other words, how to put C# (code behind) into aspx page (markup code)

Comment: One more question, how can I put multiple if/else conditions on it, right now it has only 1 "Eval("emp_note") != null" condition, what if I want to put like: if emp_note == "a" then display a specific icon, else if emp_note == "b" then display another icon?

Comment: @RonaldinhoState, for embedding C# into markup see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) or [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). As for multiple conditions - there is no easy way to embed `if`s into the markup. If you need such a complicated thing - consider defining a function in code behind class instead and calling it in markup, passing `Eval()` as an argument

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
<i class='<%# Eval("emp_note") != null ?  (Eval("emp_note") == "b" ? "icon-book" : "icon-b") : ""%>'></i>
```