# Use inline Request.QueryString to build url

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

Not sure if I'm asking this right, but I have this:

```
<a href="mypage.aspx?id=<% Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); %>&sec=map">
    Map
</a>
```

But it doesn't add the ID to the url query string. Not sure what to do cause I really don't want to have to make a bunch of literals to build this on code side.

The url I get is:

```
mypage.aspx?id=&sec=map
```

Comment: What is the url it sends you to?

Comment: just edited with the url it gives me, basically the "id" query string is blank

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in that section, see what the method returns?

Comment: First, try the easiest, replace the double-quotes of href by single-quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an `=` after the `<%` otherwise the value is not written out. You will then need to remove the semi-colon as well:

```
<a href="mypage.aspx?id=<%= Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() %>&sec=map">
    Map
</a>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) for more details on the various meanings of `<%`.