# Pass value to another page from image click in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view template column that is a glyphicon in a hyperlink control, I am trying to pass an ID value that is in the SQL datasource to a page like so :

```
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:HyperLink ID="hlResident" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" NavigateUrl="Resident/<%#= Eval("ID") %>" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                   </ItemTemplate>
```

I get the error "The Server Tag is not well formed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlResident" CssClass="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" NavigateUrl='<%# "Resident/" + Eval("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Here the change is how you bind it

```
NavigateUrl='<%# "Resident/" + Eval("ID") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%#= Eval("ID") %>
```

Should be:

```
<%# Eval("ID") %>
```

There are some different types for asp tags. The accepted answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) is very thorough on the subject.

Comment: its taking the text of the Eval and adding it to the navigate url like this:  Resident/<%#%20Eval("ID")%20%>

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigateUrl="Resident/<%#= Eval("ID") %>"
```

should be `NavigateUrl='Resident/<%# Eval("ID") %>'`

Comment: this gets me to the following url "Resident/<%#%20Eval("ID")%20%>"