# What is the %< ... >% syntax called?

Tags: javascript, html

Saw

```
animateRotate : true,
animateScale : false,
legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>" };
```

and I'm wondering what the `<% ... %>` syntax is because I've never seen it before. I'm supposing it's some way of embedding JavaScript in JavaScript strings? And can you link me to some documentation on how to use it?

Comment: It looks like ASP.NET inline expressions.  Is that code from an ASPX page (or a JavaScript file used in an ASPX page)?  See [ASP.NET “special” tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags)

Comment: Similarly, `<? ... ?>` is generally PHP (though technically `<?php ... ?>`)

Comment: No, this is completely client-side code I'm dealing with. You can see the documentation here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration.

Comment: They're templates recognized by `chart.js` in this case.

Comment: In this case, it's native `chartjs` syntax to manipulate context variables

Comment: `<% ... %>` is called stupidity. Since HTML uses `< ... >`, any framework should avoid these tags (poor RoR, and not only, templates' implementation).

Answer (score 0):

They're called `Directives` and they exist in all server-side programing language.

They have different `tags` that can perform a specific task for you in an html environment. So e.g  you can declare variables,import libraries,call methods, and perform some sort of business logic.