# What does "<%= data %>" mean in HTML

Tags: html

I see a tag like `<%= data %>` in a plain HTML file. Below is the exact code line with this context. Does any one know what does that refers to? can we do something like that in HTML?

```
<textarea class="userProfile-status-field userProfile-edit" maxlength="80"><%= status %></textarea>
```

It looks like a server tag or server code block which we generally do in `ASP.NET` but not sure what that does in HTML.

Comment: Basically we can use such in templating engine such as nodejs framework ejs.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, Ahh!!! can you elaborate a bit on the same. Or point me to a rescore

Comment: In which file extension did you see like this? Is it in .html extension?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yes it's a plain HTML file with .html extension

Comment: Then this is javascript framework which converts to template.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, yes you are right I believe. I am working with JS SDK which has a sample html file for UI and in that HTML file I saw that and got frisked.

Comment: I have answered for you. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct.

A `<%= %>` is an ASP.NET/Classic ASP tag, and its a shortcut for `<% Response.Write(data); %>`. There are many others tags as well like `<%# %>` or `<%: %>` and each suit an specific purpose.

The answer on this question [ASP.NET "special" tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) provides much information about them.

On a plain HTML file we have two options: it was copied from an aspx file and was forgotten there or someone is using a templating framework for JS, as suggested. This link http://www.sitepoint.com/overview-javascript-templating-engines/ provides more information about javascript templating engines (although I've never seen one using `<%= %>`)

Comment: This is not the answer what OP is trying look for.

Comment: Yes I very well know that but what does that do in plain HTML. HTML have no such concept of server code tag. This answer really doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The tag you're seeing is some sort of javascript template engine.

To learn more, just google about [javascript template engine](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+template+engine&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#).

You can check the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript_templates) to see how to create template engine.

Check this site to see fully demonstrated example on [such topic](https://beebole.com/pure/).

Answer (score 0):

This usually is a template syntax for evaluating variables or functions and then putting the result into HTML.