# ASP.NET - why do server-side scripting delimiters behave differently when they appear in combination with literal content in markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to understand why ASP.NET scripting delimiters `<%` and `%>` are sometimes escaped and rendered instead of substituted, depending on their position and surrounding markup, for example:

This works as expected, returning the contents of the codebehind `BASE_URL` variable or property as the page title:

```
<title><%= BASE_URL %></title>
```

While this is escaped and rendered verbatim into the page:

```
<link href="<%= BASE_URL %>_/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Again these work as expected, substituting the value of `BASE_URL`:

```
<link href="<%= "" + BASE_URL %>_/css/screen2.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<%= "//localhost:12345/" %>_/css/screen3.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This subtle differences are not covered in the wiki article on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/649458/1132334

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: "DOES NOT WORK" doesn't tell us anything

Comment: the underscores between the server-side tags and the rest of the url path in lines 2,3,4 look as if they would not belong there. please provide more information (doctype/html/rest of page header, codebehind, results, messages)

Comment: I edited your question to salvage from the "off-topic" vote because this bugs me since I first learned ASP.NET and is a perfectly valid question IMHO. research found many good articles (SO and other) on the topic of code render blocks, but none going into details about this specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is going to be pure speculation, but thought I'd share it anyway. No VS at hand to validate, so hopefully you tested that well enough before posting!

First, let us dismiss your first example, as it is kind of different and easy - it just works as expected. For the rest of the examples, which all are about code render block being declared inside double quoted markup, the pattern seems to be:

- If there are quotes inside code render block, the block is recognized
- If there are no quotes, block is not recognized

So my theory about how parser works here is like so. When parser encounters a token inside quotes, it analyzes it.

1. If there are both opening `<` and closing `>` symbols, it escapes them as it should according to XML rules into `&lt;` and `&gt;` and does not continue the toke analysis.
2. If only opening symbol is found, it recognizes it as a code rendering block start, and searches through consequent tokens for a closing part. If the closing part is found, you have a complete block, which is just a `Response.Write()` execution. If clostig tag is not found as expected, you get a syntax error.
3. If only closing symbol is found, and there was no opening symbol detected before, it is also a syntax error.

This seems to match what you are seeing. Let's run by examples.

```
<link href="<%= BASE_URL %>_/css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

`"<%= BASE_URL %>_/css/screen.css"` is a single token, contains both `<>`, so is converted into `"&lt;%= BASE_URL %&gt;_/css/screen.css"`

```
<link href="<%= "" + BASE_URL %>_/css/screen2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

`"<%= "` is one token with `<`, `" + BASE_URL %>_/css/screen2.css"` is the other with `>`. So this is recognized as code render block and is treated as `"<%= Response.Write("" + BASE_URL) %>_/css/screen2.css"`. Same with the last example.

Again, this is just a speculation that seems to match the observed behavior. I am happy to delete if this is proved wrong, or there are better answers.

Comment: once this is proven correct, it should be edited into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/649458/1132334) as a side note - it is very relevant. I always end up not mixing codebehind expressions with literals in markup because of this seemingly unstable/inconsistent behavior. razor syntax is so much smarter.