# How to fill TextBox dynamically in a GridView using a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Here is my problem : I have a GridView who render some information about an Equipment. But some of this information are in a TextBox and can be modify.
I've already create the GridView with a DataTable. How can I add dynamically information inside the each TextBox ?

Here is my GridView :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Parametre" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" style="font-size: 15px; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_selecteur">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelParam1" runat="server" Text="Sel."></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxParam1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_grandeur">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelParam2" runat="server" Text="Grandeur"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListParam2" runat="server" style="width:100%">
                <asp:ListItem value="value" Text="Temps"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="value" Text="Température"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="value" Text="[HNO3]"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="value" Text="[HF]"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem value="value" Text="[Fe]"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField runat="server" HeaderText="Unité" DataField="Unité" HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_unite"/>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_valeur">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelParam4" runat="server" Text="Min"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxParam4" runat="server" class="input_configuration_valeur"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_valeur">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelParam5" runat="server" Text="Visée"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxParam5" runat="server" class="input_configuration_valeur"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_valeur">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelParam6" runat="server" Text="Max"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxParam6" runat="server" class="input_configuration_valeur"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Here is how I fill the GridView :

```
protected void generationGridViewParametre(List<ParametreDC> equipmentParams)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn("Selection", typeof(bool));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("Grandeur", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("Unité", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("Min", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("Visée", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        dataColumn = new DataColumn("Max", typeof(string));
        dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

        DataRow dataRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < equipmentParams.Count; i++)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["Selection"] = false;
            dataRow["Unité"] = equipmentParams[i].Unite;
            //dataRow["Min"] = ?????;
            //dataRow["Visée"] = ?????;
            //dataRow["Max"] = ?????;   
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        GridView_Parametre.DataSource = dataTable;
        GridView_Parametre.DataBind();
    }
```

I don't know how to fill dataRow["Min"], dataRow["Visée"] and dataRow["Max"] ? Is it even possible with a DataTable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the "Min" column to be the actual minimum value of some other column (like the MIN aggregate function in SQL), then you can define an "Expression" for that DataColumn, like this:

```
dataColumn = new DataColumn("Min", typeof(string), "min(Grandeur)");
dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
```

This would always set the value of that column to be the minimum value of the Grandeur column.  At this point, you don't need to set the value of this column in your for loop.

If you just want to set it to a static value, then what you are doing for the other values in your for loop should work just fine.

---

A couple of other issues I noticed.

In your GridView markup, you need to set the "Text" property of the TextBox to show the actual data item for that column.  You can do this using the Eval("ColumnName") syntax, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-CssClass="th_parametre_configuration th_valeur">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="LabelParam4" runat="server" Text="Min">
        </asp:Label>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxParam4" runat="server"class="input_configuration_valeur" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Min") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However, you probably want to define an EditItemTemplate with the TextBox, and use a Label in the ItemTemplate.

To simplify your situation a little bit, you could actually just use the "BoundField" column type (like you are for Unité).

Then you can turn the `AutoGenerateEditButton` setting of the GridView and a new column with an "Edit" link will appear.  Clicking this will put all of your BoundField columns into edit mode, replacing labels with textboxes.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Parametre" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    style="font-size: 15px; width: 100%; text-align: center;"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
```

Comment: So I choose the Eval methode but I really don't understand why my first methode didn't work --' Thanks !

Comment: @PaulinBenoit Maybe I can help.  The TemplateField doesn't do any databinding automatically, so it just shows empty controls. You have to tell ASP.NET exactly what values you want to put there.  The way you do that is to use `<%# Eval("ColumnName") %>` to get a value from your datasource.  You can read more about it [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649458/861565) and [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).  I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, I can understand now ! I begin in asp.net so thank's a lot ! :)