# Variable Naming When Passing Value from Backend Code to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am passing the value of doctype variable from my c# code to javascript.

Now I am unable to find any file based on the inputs.

Does the naming convention has to be exact?

**Edit:** Added current version with `DocType` hardcoded in `onclick` javascript page.

---

**Variable:** 
`DOC_TYPE` in *ascx.cs*

`DocType` in *ascx*

**AllGroup_UserControl.ascx.cs:**

```
public partial class AllGroup_UserControl : UserControl
{
    ProductProvider provider = new ProductProvider();
    TBL_USER_PROFILEProvider uprovider = new TBL_USER_PROFILEProvider();
    DocumentProvider dprovider = new DocumentProvider();

    int DOC_TYPE;
    // Document Types
    const int G1_DOC_TYPE = 1;
    const int G2_DOC_TYPE = 2;
    const int G3_DOC_TYPE = 3;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string userName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            TBL_USER_PROFILE p = uprovider.GetUser(userName);
            if (p != null)
            {
                List<string> G1List = uprovider.GetAccessByModuleName(p.UserProfileID, "Group 1");
                List<string> G2List = uprovider.GetAccessByModuleName(p.UserProfileID, "Group 2");
                List<string> G3List = uprovider.GetAccessByModuleName(p.UserProfileID, "Group 3");

                if (G1List.Count != 0)
                {
                    DOC_TYPE = G1_DOC_TYPE;
                }
                else if (G2List.Count != 0)
                {
                    DOC_TYPE = G2_DOC_TYPE;
                }
                else if (G3List.Count != 0)
                {
                    DOC_TYPE = G3_DOC_TYPE;
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("/SitePages/AccessDeny.aspx");
                }

                Page.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

    public int DocType
    {
        get
        {
            return DOC_TYPE;
        }
    }

//rest of the code
```

**AllGroup_UserControl.ascx:**

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="openDialog('/SitePages/FileDownload.aspx?DocType=<%# DocType %>&ItemNo=<%#Eval("StoreItemNo")%>&CustomerID=<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>')">
```

---

**ADDED:**

Working code with `docType` hardcoded:

**Group1_UserControl.ascx.cs: (with doctype hardcoded)**

```
public partial class Group1_UserControl : UserControl
{

    ProductProvider provider = new ProductProvider();
    TBL_USER_PROFILEProvider uprovider = TBL_USER_PROFILEProvider();
    DocumentProvider dprovider = new DocumentProvider();
    int docType = 100;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string userName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
                TBL_USER_PROFILE p = uprovider.GetUser(userName);
                if (p != null)
                {
                    List<string> alist = uprovider.GetAccessByModuleName(p.UserProfileID, "Group 1");
                    if (alist.Count == 0)
                        Response.Redirect("/SitePages/AccessDeny.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Group1_UserControl.ascx: (with doctype hardcoded)**

```
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('/SitePages/FileDownload.aspx?DocType=100&ItemNo=<%#Eval("StoreItemNo")%>&CustomerID=<%#Eval("CustomerID")%>')">
```

Comment: could you show use the full class from `ascx.cs` and `UserControl.ascx.cs:`

Comment: updated my `ascx.cs` class file @D-Shih

Comment: i am unsure where this link was generated as you used `<%#` which is for binding (i.e. in repeater). btw, for printing a variable from the properties of the control use `<%=` instead. please see [for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649458/4648586).

Comment: *Unable to find any file based on the inputs* - can you explain what happened on page data binding event? Also what kind of URL exactly generated in `onclick` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use AJAX for that. Then you can pass values from backend to JavaScript.
Below is an example,

### Client Side Script

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/YourFunctionHere",
        data: '{name: "' + DocType + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

### The Web Method

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string YourFunctionHere(string name)
{
    return "return value here";
}
```

Comment: Adding examples in the answer than posting links alone is much more helpful

Comment: Thanks Abana, I will Update my answer with an example