# <%$ ... %> with if statement in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create a dynamic connection, which based on the value of the environment setting, defines the connection string that will be used.

So far I have done it in these two ways, but neither has worked since they show errors.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server"  
     ConnectionString='<%$ (appSettings:Environment == "Production" ? 
                            ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString : 
                            ConnectionStrings:TestConnectionString) %>' />
```

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" 
     ConnectionString='<%# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "Production" ?
                           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString : 
                           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConnectionString"].ConnectionString %>' />
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: errr, i think keeping two separate configuration files will do you more justice

Comment: "_they show errors_" What errors?

Comment: also, read [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649428/asp-net-special-tags) for what those tags do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about referencing another configuration file from the main one? You can then have a version of the configuration file for production and one for testing.
Which file is used can then be handled manually or tied into whether you are using a debug or release build.

For example:

In web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings connectionSource="connectionStringsFile.config" />
</configuration>
```

then in connectionStringsFile.config

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name = "Connection String"
     connectionString = "data server connection string here" />        
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```